# Reading excel file with pylightxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pycharm, runtime-error

My organization needs me to use **pylightxl** library to read some bulky excel xlsx files. I have never used this library before and I'm getting a strange error in pycharm. I simply do not understand what it is.
[image: a screenshot of my pycharm]

I've tried googling but there isn't much support for pylightxl on the web. Does anyone know how to help?

Comment: Are you sure your sheet name is correct? According to the documentation a "KeyError" is a result of trying to access a key in a dictionary which doesn't exist. And it seems it goes wrong over here: https://github.com/PydPiper/pylightxl/blob/master/pylightxl/pylightxl.py#L145

Comment: And make sure you are using an excelsheet which is supported, check this out: https://github.com/PydPiper/pylightxl#limitations . I actually think this is your problem, because if the sheet didn't exist it should have raised a different error earlier, looking at the sourcecode

Comment: I checked the pylightxl docs beforehand... And I am sure it supports the xlsx format... It does not support xls format.... But I am using xlsx in this case... And also I've tried renaming my sheet name, nothing still. Also the readxl command works without specifying sheetname, but in my case I get the same error... But lemme search around some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for completeness of this post it looks like there was a bug in early days of pylightxl for files that were converted from xls to xlsx, however this issue has been resolved with [#31](https://github.com/PydPiper/pylightxl/issues/31) with version 1.52+

Answer (score 0):

For those who might meet the same issue in the future, here's how i solved my issue, or rather a work around of it.

The excel files i had been given were initially in xls format, which pylightxl does not support.

I converted them to xlsx by just clicking "save as" in excel and then tried to read them in pylightxl, of which i was getting the strange error above. Must be something to do with the format

So I ended up saving it in csv instead, of which reading them was successful.

So if anyone meets this error, try different formats for the document you're trying to read